# Спор о кукушке (морфемика)

Tags: морфемика

Вышел спор с коллегой о морфемном составе слова **"кукушка".**

---

**Версия №1:** слово "кукушка" образовано от "ку-ку", поэтому слово разбирается так: **куку-шк-а**.
Этой версии придерживается и Тихонов.

**Версия №2:** слово "кукушка" образовано от "кук-ова-ть", потому что "кукушка" - это птица, которая **кукует**, то есть издает "ку-ку", поэтому в слове "кукушка" нужно выделить корень "кук", суффикс "у" (чередование -ова//у-), словообразующий суффикс "шк" и окончание "а".

---

Кто прав, на ваш взгляд?

Answer (score 2):

Никто. Потому что корень здесь **"ку-к"**, а суффикс - **ушк**.
Правда в том, что цепочку надо строить от **"куковать"**, это верно.
Загляните в этот словарь:
Лопатин В. В., Улуханов И. С. Словарь словообразовательных аффиксов современного русского языка. – М.: Издательский центр «Азбуковник», 2016. – 812 с.

Comment: А как объяснить? Почему именно УШК, какое значение у  этого суффикса? Тогда можно доказать, что другие версии неверны.

Comment: https://orfogrammka.ru/орфография/суффиксы_ышк_ышек_ешек_ушк_юшк_ушек/ А здесь же не ласкательное.

Answer (score 1):

Куковать - это искать что-то важное(детей? себя? время?) и не находить, вопрошать без ответа, и, если образовано от слова кукует, то не имеющее отношение к кукушке, а имеющее отношение к людскому поведению, растерянности, поиску. Будем куковать/куковать - скорее расхожая идиома, нежели глагол какого-то действия и какой-то конкретики.

Утка кукует:

> - Утка же между тем узнала, что дети ее умерщвлены злобною мачехою, неутешно о сем плакала и рыдала и не могла вытерпеть, чтобы к ним не полететь в церковь. И так в первую ночь прилетела в церковь, и, с гробницы на гробницу перепархивая, начала куковать: «Ку-ку, сын Данила, ку-ку, сын Гаврила, ку-ку, сын Недоседа! Не приказывала я вам на королевский двор ходить, но вы меня не послушались, и там извела вас моя мачеха». Сказка о Сарге-королевиче и Устинье-боярышне (1794-1795)

И далее. Кук - это что-то спрятанное от глаз: куколка(спрятанная гусеница), кукла(обернутая деревяшка), кулак(спрятанные пальцы), кукиш, кутать, куда, и скорее корень не кук, а опять **ку**.

Ку-ку - это забавная тавтология, куда-куда, где-где.

[Κού/πού](https://translate.academic.ru/%CE%BA%CE%BF%CF%85/el/ru/) - по-гречески, это вопрос где(именно)? как(следует)?

Отсюда и народная детская игра в ку-ку-прятки-пряталки - ищи-ищи, где-где. "Ку-ку!" значит и где-где и тебя нашли, нашёл тебя.

> Мама закрывает лицо, ребенок ищет её глаза и не может найти, где-где? Мама открывает руки, и видя ребенка говорит ку-ку - вот ты где! Вызывая у ребенка смех. То есть ку-ку - это одновременно и вопрос и ответ, а *ау-ау* - тоже, но уже на расстоянии, когда не видно.

**Ку - где, ку-ку - вот ты/я где, тут я, ты тут.**

А кук - это предмет или вещь, а не игра.

Кукушка же и кукует и подкидывает яйца в добавок, бросает, и улетает куда-то, может детей ищет: Ку-ку - где-где?

[Κού-κου](https://www.contdict.ru/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/%CE%BA%CE%BF%CF%8D) - ку-ку по-гречески.

Поэтому кукушка - это собственно звуки ку-ку и повторение слова ку - где, два раза. Где-где повторяшка - кукушка.

Зы: вот так, с детства знаешь игру, а что за игра не знаешь. Что б вы без меня делали)

> «Не стало у меня родимой матушки, На кого оставили с сиротами? Заставила век кукушкой куковать. Выду на задворочек — нет моей родимой матушки». Толстой.

Кукушкой куковать - идиома также. Где матушка родимая - нет.

В фильме "Кин-Дза-Дза" главные герои являясь цаками вынуждены здороваться "Ку!", потому что они должны выражать высшую степень растерянности, люди-кукушки, которые ничего не могут сами понять или сделать, а должны во всем слушаться высших пацаков.

Насчет морфемы и корня, корень ку и повтор его два раза ку + ку + [шка](https://gufo.me/dict/efremova/-%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0) суффикс. Насчет повтора корней и слогов, такие слова встречаются, хотя наверное это ближе к примитивной речи: мама, папа, баба(бабА, кстати, уважаемый человек), балалайка, татарин(тата, тятя - ата, главный, вождь, думаю родственное с баба), кака, кикимора, мурмурация(ну это не русское, латинское, бормотание значит), варвар...

Такие слова любят... [китайцы](https://www.liveinternet.ru/community/koryaz/post67769805/)

Comment: непонятно, что вы имели в виду)

Comment: @МиМопи Не понятно, что конкретно) или ничего не понятно? Я имел ввиду, что куковать не от корня кук. А от корня ку - которой вопрос "где?" или даже ответ - указание "где - вот здесь, именно" или даже ку+да - где это находится? Этот корень встречается как детской игре в Ку-Ку - прятки, так и ряде других слов. В слове ку-ку+шка идет повторение корня два раза, ввиду особенностей звуков кукушки. И вообще ку-ку - от кукушка, а может и наоборот, потому что кукует даже утка, когда ищет детей. То есть корень ку - ищу где/нашел вот где